# Module lombok not found

Tags: java, maven, библиотеки, модули, lombok

Доброго времени суток.

Решил в свой проект добавить библиотеку Lombok, сделал всё по инструкции предоставленной на оф. сайте Lombok. При запуске вылетает ошибка:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module lombok not found, required by space.typro.typicallauncher
```

Java 21, система сборки maven

Что я сделал не так?

**pom.xml:**

```html
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>space.typro</groupId>
    <artifactId>TypicalLauncher</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TypicalLauncher</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.bootstrapfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrapfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.30</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!--  Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run  -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>space.typro.typicallauncher/space.typro.typicallauncher.Main</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**module-info.java:**

```java
module space.typro.typicallauncher {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires lombok;

    opens space.typro.typicallauncher to javafx.fxml;
    exports space.typro.typicallauncher;
    exports space.typro.typicallauncher.controllers.scenes.subscenes;
    opens space.typro.typicallauncher.controllers.scenes.subscenes to javafx.fxml;
    exports space.typro.typicallauncher.controllers.scenes;
    opens space.typro.typicallauncher.controllers.scenes to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в моей невнимательности.

Всё, что нужно было сделать, это в `module-info.java` изменить `requires lombok;` на `requires static lombok;`